# Scroll inner element with main browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an inner element that has a fixed height and width and has `overflow-y: scroll;` set.

I want to use the main browser scrollbar to scroll the content of the inner element first, and then to continue to scroll the remainder of the page after the reaching the bottom of the content in the inner element.

Is there any way to do this in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript library, yes, its possible but you need to attempt something first and explain what specific problem you have with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript!? The sky's the limit!  Although it may not be exactly what you're looking for.  Unfortunately, you cannot hijack the "scroll" event - it is non-cancelable.

You can, however, intercept scrolling via the mousewheel -- which is how most people scroll anyway.  The other option would be to create your own Scrollbar library... but that's quite time-consuming.

(I've done that, by the way, and you're free to use it and fool around with it: http://code.fashionablydrab.com/fsb/ .  But that was like 5 years ago, so if you have any questions beyond the scope of what's covered in the How-To section, you're on your own.)

Anyway, back to the ol' "mousewheel" event.  Guess what?  It isn't standardized!  So each browser has their own way of doing it.  Firefox has come around to their new "wheel" event that has deltaX and deltaY properties and they agree with Chrome/IE's "mousewheel" event's deltaX and deltaY so you don't have to deal with the whole 'detail' problem.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhn58xzx/1/

```
var scrollInfo = {
    element: document.querySelector("#scroll")
};

var wheelEvent = document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? "mousewheel" : "wheel";

function interceptWheel(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget === scrollInfo.element) {
        return;
    }
    var st = scrollInfo.element.scrollTop,
        inc = e.deltaY;

    if (e.type === "wheel") {
        inc *= 100;
    }

    scrollInfo.element.scrollTop += inc

    if (st !== scrollInfo.element.scrollTop) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    document.querySelector("#out").innerHTML = e.deltaY;
};

document.body.addEventListener(wheelEvent, interceptWheel, false);
```

Note that it works when scrolling up and down (easy to change, just detect if e.deltaY is positive/negative before modifying the scrollTop).

And if supporting old browsers is necessary for you, then I wish you the very best of luck ;)

Comment: Awesome stuff dude, perfect! Thanks so much, much appreciated.


I've spent hours trawling the web for a solution, trying all different search phrases to describe what I was trying to do – you're a legend!